# MYSQL update join is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering can I change product status to 0 if product_id has't assigned any category_id in other table.

```
+------------+----------+  +------------+-------------+
| Product_id |  Status  |  | Product_id | cateogry_id |
+------------+----------+  +------------+-------------+
|      1     |     1    |  |     1      |      10     |
|      2     |     1    |  |     3      |      20     |
|      3     |     1    |  +------------+-------------+
+------------+----------+
```

In result i need that product_id = 2 which don't have category status be 0.
Is there one MySQL query for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple first you need to get the rows that arent in the table..

table1 is the table with the status
table2 is the table with the category id

```
           table1                     table2
+------------+----------+  +------------+-------------+
| Product_id |  Status  |  | Product_id | cateogry_id |
+------------+----------+  +------------+-------------+
|      1     |     1    |  |     1      |      10     |
|      2     |     1    |  |     3      |      20     |
|      3     |     1    |  +------------+-------------+
+------------+----------+
```

so now run this query to get the rows that don't have a category_id

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.product_id = t.product_id
WHERE t2.product_id IS NULL
```

now update table1 like so

```
UPDATE table1 t,
(   SELECT product_id 
    FROM table1 t
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.product_id = t.product_id
    WHERE t2.product_id IS NULL
) t1
SET t.status = 0
WHERE t1.product_id = t.product_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fa12b/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use left join in update with is null

```
update product p
left join product_relation pr on (p.Product_id = pr.Product_id)
set p.Status = 0
where pr.Product_id is null
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/006a0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Or even more simple.. if it is not found in table2 at all:

```
Update table1
Set status = 0
Where Product_id not in (SELECT Product_id FROM table2)
```